# Combine IdentityServer4 and ASP.NET Core Identity Framework

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

Hi everyone I have a problem with a combination of IdentityServer4 and Identity Framework.
I have 3 projects in my solution.
First, it is an OAuth project with IdentityServer4. This project has the next configuration:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using IdentityServer4;
using IdentityServer4.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Platform.OAuth.Data;
using Platform.OAuth.Data.Models;

namespace Platform.OAuth
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                    x => x.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(ApplicationContext).Assembly.FullName));
            });

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationContext>();

            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
                .AddInMemoryPersistedGrants()
                .AddInMemoryClients(new List<Client>
                {
                    new Client
                    {
                        ClientId = "api-client",
                        ClientName = "API Client",
                        AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,

                        RequireConsent = false,

                        ClientSecrets =
                        {
                            new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                        },

                        RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5002/signin-oidc" },
                        PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5002/signout-callback-oidc" },

                        AllowedScopes =
                        {
                            IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                            IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                            "api1"
                        },
                        AllowOfflineAccess = true
                    }
                })
                .AddInMemoryApiScopes(new List<ApiScope>
                {
                    new ApiScope("api1", "My API")
                })
                .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>();

            services.AddAuthentication();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseIdentityServer();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Second, it is API project that contains some API which I want to protect. This project has next configuration:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;

namespace Api
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
            });

            services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
            .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "https://localhost:44392"; /// <-- OAuth project url

                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateAudience = false
                };
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Thrid, It is client project that makes calls for both API.

```cs
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var disco = await client.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync("https://localhost:44392");
            if (disco.IsError)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(disco.Error);
                return;
            }

            var tokenResponse = await client.RequestClientCredentialsTokenAsync(new ClientCredentialsTokenRequest
            {
                Address = disco.TokenEndpoint,

                ClientId = "api-client",
                ClientSecret = "secret",
                Scope = "api1"
            });

            if (tokenResponse.IsError)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(tokenResponse.Error);
                return;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(tokenResponse.Json);

            client.SetBearerToken(tokenResponse.AccessToken);
            var testResponse = await client.GetAsync("https://localhost:44392/WeatherForecast");
            if(testResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var content = await testResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(JArray.Parse(content));
            }

            var apiClient = new HttpClient();
            apiClient.SetBearerToken(tokenResponse.AccessToken);
            Console.WriteLine("==============================================================");
            var response = await apiClient.GetAsync("https://localhost:44369/WeatherForecast");
            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
            }
            else
            {
                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(JArray.Parse(content));
            }
        }
```

Both web API projects have default `WeatherForecastController` which I've protected by `AuthorizeAttribute` And when the client makes a request with a token to API, the action returns data, but when a request for OAuth, action returns 404 error. I think it is good for the `OAuth` project but not for the `API` because `API` and 'OAuth' projects don't have authorized users. But why the `API` return data?

Answer (score 0):

Receiving 404 should not be related with any auth issue, since it is the HTTP "not found" code, retrieved precisely when the resource you tried to access is not found with the URL that was used.

Concerning the data received from the API endpoint, it is a successful response, right? I will assume it is.

Following your client code snippet, it seems to me that you get a token from the Identity Server and perform a GET request with the token set. Since the token is valid, the client is authenticated and the API recognizes it.

If you set the `[Authorize]` attribute without any specified policy, the default applies. The default is: `if you are authenticated, you are also authorized`; this means that providing a valid token is enough to be authorized - which you do.

I would say that this is why you get a successful response. More information [here](https://www.google.com/amp/s/andrewlock.net/setting-global-authorization-policies-using-the-defaultpolicy-and-the-fallbackpolicy-in-aspnet-core-3/amp/).

Comment: @Алексей did this help?